# Calculate number of working days in ADF pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have tow columns named start_date and end_date, on the basis of this how can I calculate Number of Working Days(Mon-Fri) in my ADF pipeline.

E.g:
start_date - 25/01/2022
end_date - 04/02/2022

Working days = 9

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure function to calculate weekdays.

Sample Code for Body –

```
{
“total_days”:365,
“working_days”:253,
“holidays_removed”:9,
“start_date”:”yyyy-mm-dd”,
“end_date”:” yyyy-mm-dd”
}
```

Refer this [article](https://ryanmaclean365.com/2019/12/12/calculate-working-days-in-a-time-period-using-power-automate/) by RYAN MACLEAN for more information

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I wanted to count the number of working days between a given date and today's date and I solved it as follows:

NOTE: This will work in any Tool given you have 2 functions, one that gives you the day of the week and another function that returns the number of days between 2 dates.

I used the following function and a couple of helper columns in mapping Data Flow: 
[dayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#dayOfWeek): the function return the day of week (1- Sunday, 2- Monday .. 7- Saturday)

Then I used the minus function to substract the number of days from current date - column date 
Let's call the column **H_DaysDiff**

```
minus(currentDate(), DateCol)
```

Then I used the following function to get the number of full weeks between the 2 dates (to count every saturday and sunday)
Let's call the column **H_WholeWeek**

```
floor(minus(currentDate(), DateCol) / 7)
```

Then I used the following column to determine the number of days remaining that do not make up a full week (Note: Possible Values [0..6] ). Let's call this column **H_RemainingDaysForFullWeek**

```
minus(currentDate(), DateCol) % 7
```

And finally we have the column that contains the DayOfWeek **H_DayOfWeekNumber**

```
dayOfWeek(DateCol)
```

After creating those helper columns, I used the case statement as follows:

```
case(
/* Possible values for remaining days for full week [0..6] */
/* Day Of Week = Saturday && if remaining days >= 1 we have to add + 1 for Sunday   | toInteger((H_WholeWeek * 2) + 1) < counts the number of weekends */
H_DayOfWeekNumber == 7 && (H_DayOfWeekNumber + H_RemainingDaysForFullWeek) >= 8 , H_DaysDiff - toInteger((H_WholeWeek * 2) + 1), 

/* Day Of Week not Saturday && if remaining days == 7 (Day of week + remaining days = Saturday) we have to add + 1 for Saturday */
 H_DayOfWeekNumber != 7 && (H_DayOfWeekNumber + H_RemainingDaysForFullWeek) == 7, H_DaysDiff - toInteger((H_WholeWeek * 2) + 1),

/* Day Of Week not Saturday && if remaining days > 7 (Day of week + remaining days = Sunday or more ) we have to add + 2 for Saturday and Sunday */
 H_DayOfWeekNumber != 7 && (H_DayOfWeekNumber + H_RemainingDaysForFullWeek) > 7, H_DaysDiff - toInteger((H_WholeWeek * 2) + 2), 

/* Else */
H_DaysDiff - toInteger(H_WholeWeek * 2)
```

)

This will count the number of working days between a given date and today excluding the start date.

i.e: 
DateCol: 21.06.2023 Today: 22.06.2023 will return 1
DateCol: 19.06.2023 Today: 22.06.2023 will return 3
DateCol: 18.06.2023 *(Sunday)* Today: 22.06.2023 will return 4
DateCol: 17.06.2023 *(Saturday)* Today: 22.06.2023 will return 4
DateCol: 16.06.2023 Today: 22.06.2023 will return 4 (Start Date is not included in the count)
DateCol: 15.06.2023 Today: 22.06.2023 will return 5